# How to rectify unknown type name 'PyTypeObject' error when using Python.h?

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.x, embedding

I used Python.h to write the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

i get the following error

```
81  1   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\dictobject.h    [Error] unknown type name 'PyTypeObject'
81  1   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\dictobject.h    [Error] unknown type name 'PyTypeObject'
```

multiple times
and

```
35  5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\funcobject.h    [Error] unknown type name 'vectorcallfunc'
```

one time.

also these

```
254 35  C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\cpython\abstract.h  [Error] unknown type name 'Py_buffer'
175 53  C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\cpython\abstract.h  [Error] unknown type name '_Py_Identifier'
```

when compiling it also opens objimpl.h where it mentions a line where the word 'PyTypeObject' is present

I use DevCpp-gcc-4.9.2

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html? I don't know if it helps but _Note Since Python may define some pre-processor definitions which affect the standard headers on some systems, you must include Python.h before any standard headers are included._

Comment: I tried including Python.h first,But still same error occurs.